# What effect, if any, would each of the following actions have on the calculated concentration of the NaOH in this experiment?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration

What effect, if any, would each of the following actions have on the calculated concentration of the NaOH in this experiment? (e.g. would the calculated concentration be higher, lower or the same?) Treat each action separately and explain your answer.

1-You overshoot the endpoint.

2-The beaker that you put the NaOH in already had a small amount of distilled water in it.

3-You add a small amount of water to the conical flask containing the KHP.

4-You forget to add indicator.

5-There is an air bubble in the tip of the burette before you start the titration but it isn’t there after the titration.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a homework for us? Explain your efforts that you made to solve your own question, or else the question will be closed due to lack of such. We are not a homework help service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the sodium hydroxide in the flask and not in the burette.

1) if you over shot you will have more of titre in the flask that you want to it would be assumed that you had to add more titire to reach the end point so the concentration of the NaOH would be mistaken to be stronger than it actually is.

2)if the NaOH has added to a flask with water in it, it should make a difference as you will still be placing the same number of moles in the flask for the titration.

3) dont know what KHP is

4)if you didn't add any indicator then it wouldn't affect anything as long as the reaction still reached the end point. but you wouldn't know where the end point is so the results are pretty useless unless you knew how much to titrate.

5)if there is a bubble in the burette then you would have added less of the titre than you think you have added. this will mean that calculations will so the NaOH to be stronger than it actually is.

Comment: Hi,  and welcome to our site! Although we appreciate the time you took to answer this, we typically don't answer questions that are likely to be closed so as not to encourage further low quality questions.

Comment: ok, ill try to remember that. although it did only just read that it as was likely to be closed down

Comment: no the naoh iis in the burette and the khp is in the flask

Comment: well you should have said that in your question as it wasn't clear so I took it to be the typical way round.